# ¿Como cambiar lenguaje de fecha Data pipe Angular 6?

Tags: angular

Quisiera cambiar el idioma de la fecha de mi app para que sea de argentina, probé con esta configuración viendo la documentación de angular pero sigue sin cambiar. Queda la configuración por defecto que es en-US. No me muestra ningún error por consola

app.module.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeEsAr from '@angular/common/locales/es-AR';
registerLocaleData(localeEsAr);
```

app.component.html

```
<td>{{resultado.date?.seconds * 1000| date:'fullDate'}}</td>
```

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas solucionó tu problema considera marcarla como aceptada :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lo que te falta es importar los locales de angular common locales, tambien registrarlos para poder usarlos, eso deberia solucionar tu error de

> 'Missing locale data for the locale "es-AR"'

y si te sigue tirando el mismo error revisa tu carpeta de locales si es que esta contiene es-Ar, en tu caso solo deberías importar es-Ar, en mi ejemplo muestra varios otros locales

```
    import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent } from '../src/app/app.component';
    import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

    // importar locales
    import localePy from '@angular/common/locales/es-PY';
    import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
    import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';
    import localeEsAr from '@angular/common/locales/es-AR';

    // registrar los locales con el nombre que quieras utilizar a la hora de proveer
    registerLocaleData(localePy, 'es');
    registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt');
    registerLocaleData(localeEn, 'en')
    registerLocaleData(localeEsAR, 'es-Ar');

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      // Aqui usas el nombre que hayas colocado al locale, en este caso es-Ar o pt o en, etc
      providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es-Ar' } ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es cómo estás configurando la localización. De la documentación oficial, esto es lo que va en `app.module.ts`:

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from '../src/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' } ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

El método que usás vos para registrar la locale, entiendo que sirve si vas a usar múltiples localizaciones y no una sola.

En ese caso, tendrías que indicar qué locale vas a utilizar en la pipe.

Comment: Eso ya lo habia hecho tambien, pero en la consola me aparecia el siguien error: 
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "es-AR".' for pipe 'DatePipe' 
Evidentemente algo mas falta para que el pipe puede encontrar ese locale